# How to quit MBASIC and return to CP/M?

Tags: cp-m, microsoft-basic

I've tried everything I can think of. `EXIT` `QUIT` `END` `STOP` `BYE` `Q`…

Comment: Oops? What happened?

Comment: @Raffzahn: You wrote essentially the same answer as mine, so I deleted mine :)

Comment: Err. Wasn't my intention, I can delete it. Your's is as fine. Took me some time find a fitting link.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

> How to quit MBASIC and return to CP/M?

**SYSTEM**

See Section D integration to CP/M, [page D-4](https://archive.org/details/BASIC-80_MBASIC_Reference_Manual/page/n139/mode/2up) of the MBASIC Manual

Comment: Ha, I (mis)remembered that DEC TOPS-10 BASIC used SYSTEM to exit from BASIC, but at least in early versions, it used MONITOR.  CP/M, of course, acquired some aspects of its command structure from DEC systems.